# ASP.NET Passing item id on button action

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm quite of a newbie in ASP.Net and i'm currently following a book tutorial.

There's something wrong happening even though i've followed every step. I'll try my best to explain it.

The application consists of a simple list of items and adding them to a cart. In my controller i have two functions Add/Remove which takes an productId parameter. The problem is that it's not well binded and as a result the productId parameter is null when i execute the code. 
Here after the interesting part for the code..

**CartController.cs**

```
    namespace SportStore.Controllers {
    public class CartController : Controller {

    public ViewResult Index(Cart cart, string returnUrl)
    {
        return View(new CartIndexViewModel
        {
            Cart = cart,
            ReturnUrl = returnUrl
        });
    }

    public RedirectToRouteResult AddToCart(Cart cart, int? productId, string returnUrl)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("\n_ _ _ _ _ Product Id selected: " + productId);

        Product product = Singleton.GetInstance().Products.GetAll()
                .FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == productId);

        if (product != null)
        {
           cart.AddItem(product, 1);
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index", new { returnUrl });
    }
...
... Remove function
```

**ProductSummary.cshtml**

```
@model SportStore.Models.Entities.Product
@using SportStore.HtmlHelpers

<div class="well">
    <h3>
        @Model.Id
        <strong>@Model.Name</strong>
        <span class="pull-right label label-primary">@Model.Price.ToString("c")</span>
    </h3>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("AddToCart", "Cart"))
    {
        <div class="pull-right">
            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Id)
            @Html.Hidden("returnUrl", Request.Url.PathAndQuery)
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Add To Cart" />
        </div>
    }
    <span class="lead">@Model.Description</span>
</div>
```

What I don't understand is in the views the Ids are shown correctly
But when calling for the action it won't transmit the Id. 
What am I missing ? (if you need some others parts of the code tell me i'll put it as an answer)

Well, if someone has something that might help me out i'd be glad.

Comment: Your no posting back a value for `Id` but your method has a parameter named `int? productId` - it needs to be `int? Id`

Comment: damn ! it works only by switch "productId" >> "id" ! i knew it was some tiny issue. Thanks a lot stephen!

Comment: So when i pass parameters on such actions it has to match the model parameter name without the first uppercase letter is that right ?

Comment: Yes that is how the default model binder will bind model from client side (JSON) to server side (C#) model.